# Concatenating array rows php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This may be a stupid question, so please go easy on me if so.

I have a range of queries (MySQL) returning multidimensional arrays.

I then use these array items to populate variables in a string in a foreach loop.

I then need this string to populate a javascript graph so the format of the data wants to be perfect. this idea works with 1 multidimensional array.

However. To do multiple graphs (e.g comparison line graph) I need to express all the data in the same row.

So what I need to be able to do is if possible merge row to row of the array, rather than add it to the end.

Ill show you my working:

```
foreach ($graph_month as $month) :
        $first .= ' { year: "'.$month['month'].'",';
        endforeach;

        foreach ($graph_data1 as $data) :
        $second1 .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;

        foreach ($graph_data2 as $data) :
        $second2 .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;

        foreach ($graph_data3 as $data) :
        $second3 .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;

        foreach ($graph_data4 as $data) :
        $second4 .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;

        foreach ($graph_data5 as $data) :
        $second5 .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;
```

So each of the foreach's is populating a little section of the javascript required, however I need to be able to concatenate all these rows on the right of each other.

e.g

a `foreach` that can produce:

`$first.$second1.$second2.$second3.$second4.$second5`

Is this possible, would it be possible to add [i] and [i++] to each variable.

Comment: Is the expected end result JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you could eliminate the extra `foreach` lines by generating variables like this:

```
foreach ($graph_month as $month):

    for ($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) {
        //$graph_data$i becomes $graph_data1, then $graph_data2 etc.
        foreach ($graph_data$i as $data) :
            $variable .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
        endforeach;
    }

// and so on
endforeach;
```

The outcome of this script is, as you requested, something of this shape:

`{year: month, title: value title: value`

We can tweak it a little like this:

```
foreach ($graph_month as $month):

    $variable .= ' { year: "'.$month['month'].'",';

    for ($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) {
        //$graph_data$i becomes $graph_data1, then $graph_data2 etc.
        foreach ($graph_data$i as $data) :
            $variable .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
            if ($i != 5) {
                $variable .= ", ";
            }
        endforeach;
    }

    $variable .= 

// and so on
endforeach;
```

and it becomes:

`{ year: month, 'title': 'value', 'title': 'value', ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can put same variable:

```
foreach ($graph_month as $month) {
    $variable .= ' { year: "'.$month['month'].'",';
}

foreach ($graph_data1 as $data) {
    $variable .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
}

foreach ($graph_data2 as $data) {
    $variable .= ' "'.$data['title'].'": '.$data['totalValue'].' ';
}

// and so on
```

they will concatenate on every loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop like this...

```
<?php 

for($i=0;$i<count($graph_month);$i++)
{
    $all_values1 = $graph_data1[$i]['title'] . $graph_data1[$i]['totalValue'];
    $all_values2 = $graph_data2[$i]['title'] . $graph_data2[$i]['totalValue'];
    $all_values3 = $graph_data3[$i]['title'] . $graph_data3[$i]['totalValue'];
    $all_values4 = $graph_data4[$i]['title'] . $graph_data4[$i]['totalValue'];
    $all_values5 = $graph_data5[$i]['title'] . $graph_data5[$i]['totalValue'];
}
```

?>

No need to run too may for loop. It will take some extra time to execute...

Try like this....

Answer (score 0):

Use Empty String

```
$string = '';
```

Then use this variable with every for loop

```
foreach($array1 as $value){
$string.= $value['some_data'];
}

foreach($array2 as $value){
$string.= $value['some_data'];
}
```

Use this $string as final result

Answer (score 0):

Let PHP worry about the JSON formatting just build the object correctly.

```
<?php

$tojson = array(
     0 => array(),
     1 => array(),
     2 => array(),
     3 => array(),
     4 => array(),
     5 => array()
);

foreach($graph_month as $month)
    $tojson[0]['year'] = $month['month'];

foreach($graph_data1 as $data)
    $tojson[1][$data['title']] = $data['totalValue'];

foreach($graph_data2 as $data)
    $tojson[2][$data['title']] = $data['totalValue'];

foreach($graph_data3 as $data)
    $tojson[3][$data['title']] = $data['totalValue'];

foreach($graph_data4 as $data)
    $tojson[4][$data['title']] = $data['totalValue'];

foreach($graph_data5 as $data)
    $tojson[5][$data['title']] = $data['totalValue'];

$json = json_encode($tojson);

?>
```